# Am I writing this code wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This looks wrong to me, am i right? This is the code that I am using:

```
_editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                              target:self
                                              action:@selector(editButtonPressed:)];

// If we have no threads we don't have the edit button
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = _editButton ; nil;
```

Mainly I am concerned with `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = _editButton ; nil;` the `_editButton ; nil;` looks wrong to me.

Should the code look like this? `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = _editButton;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not *wrong* per se, but it is unnecessary.  The `;` after `_editButton` ends the statement making `nil;` a statement of its own, and as you might imagine that does nothing whatsoever.  The two are functionally identical, so you may as well take out the extra code.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used this particular type before, but your main indicator is prooobably if it works as intended (+ if it shows up on a debugger as correct, but that's a given).